# Unable to merge branch in in-house TFS GIT from Visual Studio 2013

Tags: git, merge, visual-studio-2013

I've looked around SO and either can't find an answer close to my question or don't fully understand the answers being explained.

I am having an issue trying to merge a development branch into the master branch (both origin branches)

I receive the error `2 uncommitted changes would be overwritten by merge`

I have switched branches in an attempt to commit these 2 changes, though don't have any. There are no changes to commit on my master.

I wasn't sure if it was perhaps related to a developer having left, though figured TFS wouldn't know about anything he may not have committed.

I also, some time ago, had to change the directory structure of the project on my machine, though have had no issues with push/pull. Just this one merge issue

So - is there a way (if you could please explain, as pretty new with TFS & GIT) to force the merge so that my development branch can be merged into the master branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in VS 2013 that results from your having mixed line endings in that file.

We fixed one of the occurrences of this bug in VS 2013 Update 3; upgrading *may* help you.  We fixed the second occurrence of this bug in the next update to VS 2013 (Update 4), though I do not know when we will release the next update.

This bug is due to Visual Studio being overly aggressive in looking for unstaged changes; it's detecting a file in your working directory that has mixed line endings as modified.  (Git is not showing this as an unstaged change, but it *would* if you were to blow away its local filesystem cache and make it examine the filesystem.)

Fundamentally, you have mixed line endings that do not match the settings in your `core.autocrlf` or `.gitattributes` file.

You can either:

1. Use `git-merge` from the command-line and ignore the fact that your line endings are mismatched, or
2. Fix the line endings in your files by ensuring that you have a `.gitattributes` in your repository, then normalizing the line endings in your files according to the [suggestions that GitHub provides](https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings).

Comment: You bet; sorry about the inconvenience.  This bug was, regrettably, all my fault.

Comment: We all make them, it's not always possible to catch everything :)