# Error was raised by libgit2. Category = Ssh

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-2013

I have been using VS2013 git. I had some problems with renaming my files to use lowercase letters, so I had to rename then manually in Github. Now, when I try to sync files I get this error:

***An error occurred. Detailed message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Ssh (MergeConflict).
14 uncommitted changes would be overwritten by merge***

When I try to push I get this error:

***There are new remote changes.  You must pull them before you can push.***

I have 9 incoming commits and 1 outgoing commit in VS2013.

I have tried using the Git Shell to pull/push, and there it says ***"Everything up-to date."***

I'm not too good at using git, and this is a problem I can't solve.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to merge branch in in-house TFS GIT from Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919455/unable-to-merge-branch-in-in-house-tfs-git-from-visual-studio-2013)

Answer (score -1):

1. When you see this kind of error, just go to command prompt. You will have access through "Action".
2. When you entered the command: "git pull" you will see a lot of files in conflict but unable to merge. You will have to remove your files.
3. After removing these files and entering the commands:

   git stash
    git pull
4. Reference there: http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=3820

Comment: Although this link may contain the answer to the question, link-based answers are discouraged. Please incorporate the text that answers the question into your response.